# RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'lxml.etree' does not match runtime version 2.7

Tags: python, version, lxml, typeerror

I am using python 2.7 and I am trying to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/), but when I try using lxml.etree, I get this error:

> RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'lxml.etree' does not match runtime version 2.7

And then this error:

> File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 123, in init lxml.etree (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:160385)
>   TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not unicode

I have tried installing using easy_install and using pip

After installing, I see this message:

> Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lxml-2.3.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the right easy_install and pip. When easy_install and pip get installed, they're 'mated' with a version of python via a symlink by whatever version of python you used to install them.

If you're using python-2.7, make sure you use easy_install-2.7, or pip-2.7. Odds are the pip you used was mated with 2.6 and it's symlink is 'pip -> pip2.6'.

If you're using python2.7, make sure easy_install and pip's symlinks are set correctly. (This should be as simple as finding easy_install, and replacing it to point to easy_install-2.7, then run easy_install pip and pip will replace it's own link.

To replace easy_install with the correct version:

```
wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
python2.7 ez_setup.py
```

That should replace your existing easy_install with one that uses the correct python version. Reinstall pip using it, and whatever other modules you need.

Comment: i try removing easy_install and reinstalling it,how do i find easy_install and make it point the right one ?

Comment: `which easy_install` to find it and then `ls -l \`which easy_install\`` to see where it's pointing.

Comment: its not a symlink i have easy_install inside /usr/bin

Comment: Modified my answer to explain how to replace easy-install the quickest/easiest way.