# Trouble with Scipy for Python 2.6 on Mac OS Lion

Tags: python, macos, numpy, scipy

I installed numpy and scipy on preinstalled python 2.6 on Mac OS Lion using the following instructions:
[numpy and scipy for preinstalled python 2.6.7 on mac OS Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442970/numpy-and-scipy-for-preinstalled-python-2-6-7-on-mac-os-lion#)
Numpy works just fine; however, with `from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix`, I get the following errors. Is there anything I need to do to resolve this issue?

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/lil.py:21: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'scipy.sparse._csparsetools' does not match runtime version 2.7
  from . import _csparsetools
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/__init__.py:150: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._shortest_path' does not match runtime version 2.7
  from ._shortest_path import shortest_path, floyd_warshall, dijkstra,\
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_validation.py:5: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._tools' does not match runtime version 2.7
  from ._tools import csgraph_to_dense, csgraph_from_dense,\
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/__init__.py:152: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._traversal' does not match runtime version 2.7
  from ._traversal import breadth_first_order, depth_first_order, \
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/__init__.py:154: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._min_spanning_tree' does not match runtime version 2.7
  from ._min_spanning_tree import minimum_spanning_tree
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/__init__.py:155: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.6 of module 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._reordering' does not match runtime version 2.7
  from ._reordering import reverse_cuthill_mckee, maximum_bipartite_matching
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9465303/2963903) suggests that you might have used the wrong version of `pip` or `easy_install`. Check their versions.

Comment: @leewangzhong: Thank you. I followed exact directions provided in the above link. I mean sudo easy_install-2.6 pip and sudo pip-2.6 install numpy etc. Do I need to use a different version?

Comment: What about the `python` version? In the code with that line, do `import sys; print sys.version`.

Comment: I get 2.7.1 (r271:86832)

Comment: Well there's your answer: You're running your Python 2.6 script in Python 2.7. Learn about the shebang for specifying a script's Python version.

Comment: Well, I appreciate your patience with me. Would you please be a bit more specific? Do I need to install Scipy for 2.7 as well? I installed Numpy exactly the same way and it works just fine. Thank you so much

Comment: You installed Scipy for Python 2.6. You are running your script in Python 2.7. It may be coincidence that it worked before, but I don't know for sure. There are two solutions: Run your script and specify Python 2.6 (usually `python26 myscript.py`, or putting `#!/usr/bin/python26` as the first line of the program and then running `./myscript.py` directly), or install it for 2.7.

Comment: I put #!/usr/bin/python26 at the very first line and tried it. No luck...

Comment: You have to learn more about what `#!` means on Unix-likes. `/usr/bin/python26` should be replaced by whatever the path to your `python26` interpreter is. Have you tried running `python26 myscript.py`?

Comment: I use Eclipse and in preferences, I have /usr/bin/python as the interpreter...

Comment: Then you have to figure out how to call Python 2.6 in a terminal window, and then use that as the interpreter instead.